# Regular Expression validate and extract a string starts with a decimal or fraction

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to know how to go about creating a regular expression with the following conditions:

1. String must start with a decimal or fraction
2. Decimal should be positive and up to 2 decimal places
3. Fractions should be a fraction on it's own or one whole number and fraction i.e. 1 1/2, 3/4 and be separated by a space. *(Could be cool if someone wrote 1 and 1/2 that it new it would be 1 1/2 but not necessary*
4. List item

I would to validate that a string starts with either a decimal or a fraction and get extracted values out of it

**Valid Examples**

```
"1 cup" = VALID = Extracted values: (1) (cup)
".5 cup" = VALID = Extracted values: (0.5) (cup)
"1.0 cup" = VALID = Extracted values: (1.0) (cup)
"1.10 cup" = VALID = Extracted values: (1.10) (cup)
"1/2 cup" = VALID = Extracted values: (1/2) (cup)
"1 1/2 cup" = VALID = Extracted values: (1 1/2) (cup)
"1 and 1/2 cup" = VALID = Extracted values: (1 1/2) (cup)
"1 and a 1/2 cup" = VALID = Extracted values: (1 1/2) (cup)
"1 & 1/2 cup" = VALID = Extracted values: (1 1/2) (cup)
```

**Invalid Examples**

```
"1 1/2 1/4 1/4 cup" = INVALID (only allow whole and fraction, or one fraction)
"1.034 cup" = INVALID (2 decimal places only)    
"cup 1/2" = INVALID (not the start of the string)
```

**EDIT**
What I have so far:

Parsing Fractions:

```
\d*\s*(and*|and a*|\s*)\d+\/?\d*(.*)$
```

Parsing Decimals:

```
^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

My combined version:

```
(\d*\s*&|and*|and a*|\s*\s*\d+\/?\d*)|(\d{0,2}\.\d{1,2})*(.*)$
```

Just don't know how to join the 2 properly and it it can be better optimized?, and the invalid one still parse

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Regards DotnetShadow

Comment: I have edited my post to include what I have so far if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me with your examples above (using [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) to test):

```
^(?<WholeNumber>\d+){0,1}(?:\s(?<JoinWord>&|and|and\sa)?\s?)?(?<Decimal>\.\d{1,2})?(?<Fraction>(?<Numerator>\d+)\/(?<Denominator>\d+)){0,1}(?:\s(?<Unit>cup))$
```

You'll notice that I used named capture groups for the various components. I'll leave it to you to parse out the groups and join them meaningfully (for example add the whole number to the value of the decimal value divided by 100 and add the value of numerator divided by denominator).

You can also add an additional patterns for other supported "unit" and also other supported "joinWord".

**Edited**: Added my suggestions as per my comments.

Comment: And actually, you might use (?<WholeNumber>\d+) for the whole number part instead...

Comment: And perhaps move the first "\s" (space) into the "JoinWord" capture group somehow.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was after, much appreciated. I can learn a lot from this

Comment: No worries... A good regex builder/tester tool is the key to writing these things... I really like the one I linked above - Regex Hero.

Comment: Yeah I was using Regexlib but your one is heaps better, just didn't release how powerful ? is in regex. What is the difference between ? and ?:

Comment: I've used "?" in a few forms there, namely: "?" after a capture to represent optional (this is the same as {0,1}). Also "?:" at the start of a group (recognised by parentheses) means it's a non-capturing group. Then "?<>" at the start of a group means it's a named-capture group (very useful for distinguishing pattern pieces and also for processing the match latter on).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need regex to solve this problem. Consider following solution:

1. Write function IsFraction(string s) that checks if string is a valid fraction (can it be 3/2, for example?).
2. Split input string, check that last item is not a number of any kind - that would be unit.
3. Remove all non-number and non-fraction items from list.
4. Verify that remaining items count is less than 3.
5. If count of items is 2, verify first is natural number and second is a fraction. -> result
6. If count is 1, verify that it's a fraction or decimal. -> result

More time (maybe) for initial writing, but easier to maintain and extend.

P.S. Use `int.TryParse` and `decimal.TryParse` with and within `IsFraction`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice alternative will try it