# Convert Fraction regex: pcre (php) to javascript

Tags: regex

I need convert below prce (php) regex to javascript regex, how can I do that :

```
^(?<WholeNumber>\d+){0,1}(?:\s(?<JoinWord>&|and|and\sa)?\s?)?(?<Decimal>\.\d{1,2})?(?<Fraction>(?<Numerator>\d+)\/(?<Denominator>\d+)){0,1}$
```

http://regex101.com/r/uU0jW7/1

Comment: Why use {0,1} in (?<WholeNumber>\d+){0,1} ? It match 1 or more digit 0 or + ?

Comment: @walid toumi: 
I'm realy don't know, please view to more info
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7802239/3007147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ^(\d+){0,1}(?:\s(&|and|and\sa)?\s?)?(\.\d{1,2})?((\d+)\/(\d+)){0,1}$
```

You can use this and kee track of groups for your needs.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uU0jW7/2

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't support named groups, so you have to use generic capturing groups instead.

Your regex can also be modified in some places (remember that `{0,1}` is `?`), to:

```
^(\d*)(?:\s(&|and(?:\sa)?)?\s?)?(\.\d\d?)?((\d+)\/(\d+))?$
```